# Rounding decimals in nested data structures in Python

Tags: python, printing, string-formatting, rounding

I have a program which deals with nested data structures where the underlying type usually ends up being a decimal.  e.g.

```
x={'a':[1.05600000001,2.34581736481,[1.1111111112,9.999990111111]],...}
```

Is there a simple pythonic way to print such a variable but rounding all floats to (say) 3dp and not assuming a particular configuration of lists and dictionaries? e.g.

```
{'a':[1.056,2.346,[1.111,10.000],...}
```

I'm thinking something like 
`pformat(x,round=3)` or maybe

```
pformat(x,conversions={'float':lambda x: "%.3g" % x})
```

except I don't think they have this kind of functionality.  Permanently rounding the underlying data is of course not an option.

Comment: how about running a loop like [floor(x*1000)/1000.0 for x in a] ?

Comment: that only works for lists of numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will recursively descend dicts, tuples, lists, etc. formatting numbers and leaving other stuff alone.

```
import collections.abc
import numbers

def pformat(thing, formatfunc):
    if isinstance(thing, dict):
        return type(thing)((key, pformat(value, formatfunc)) for key, value in thing.items())
    if isinstance(thing, collections.abc.Container):
        return type(thing)(pformat(value, formatfunc) for value in thing)
    if isinstance(thing, numbers.Number):
        return formatfunc(thing)
    return thing

def formatfloat(thing):
    return "%.3g" % float(thing)

x={'a':[1.05600000001,2.34581736481,[8.1111111112,9.999990111111]],
'b':[3.05600000001,4.34581736481,[5.1111111112,6.999990111111]]}

print(pformat(x, formatfloat))
```

If you want to try and convert everything to a float, you can do

```
try:
    return formatfunc(thing)
except Exception:
    return thing
```

instead of the last three lines of the function.

Comment: Trying to make this function work - throws an error : TypeError: pformat() missing 1 required positional argument: 'formatfunc'

Comment: This code is fixed by adding an argument on pformat(value, formatfunc)

Comment: Thanks @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ for fixing that!

Comment: As of Python 3.10, strings are instances of `collections.abc.Container`, leading to the code above producing erroneous outputs if the input contains strings.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach assuming you have lists of floats:

```
>>> round = lambda l: [float('%.3g' % e) if type(e) is not list else round(e) for e in l]
>>> print({k: round(v) for k, v in x.items()})
{'a': [1.06, 2.35, [1.11, 10.0]]}
```

Comment: A lambda referring to itself by name is just wrong, this is what named functions or the y-combinator are for :). He also said the type "usually ends up being decimal" so I think sometimes they won't be `float`able.

Comment: I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to swap `round = lambda l: ...` with `def round(l): return ...` :D

Comment: But the y-combinator is awesome and there is never a reason to use it in Python!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> b = []
>>> x={'a':[1.05600000001,2.34581736481,[1.1111111112,9.999990111111]]}
>>> for i in x.get('a'):
        if type(i) == type([]):
            for y in i:
                print("%0.3f"%(float(y)))
        else:
            print("%0.3f"%(float(i)))


    1.056
    2.346
    1.111
    10.000
```

The problem Here is we don't have flatten method in python, since I know it is only 2 level list nesting I have used `for loop`.