# Round floats in a nested dictionary recursively

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I'm trying to round up float values in a nested dictionary that has other values as well. I looked at this thread - [Rounding decimals in nested data structures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076254/rounding-decimals-in-nested-data-structures-in-python)

Trying to implement the function like this:

```
import collections
import numbers

def formatfloat(x):
    return "%.3g" % float(x)

def pformat(dictionary, function):
    if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        return type(dictionary)((key, pformat(value)) for key, value in dictionary.items())
    if isinstance(dictionary, collections.Container):
        return type(dictionary)(pformat(value) for value in dictionary)
    if isinstance(dictionary, numbers.Number):
        return formatfunc(dictionary)
    return dictionary

x={'a':[1.05600000001,2.34581736481,[8.1111111112,9.999990111111]], 
   'b':[3.05600000001,4.34581736481,[5.1111111112,6.999990111111]]}

pformat(x, formatfloat)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: pformat() missing 1 required positional argument: 'function'
```

The answer was marked correct so I was wondering if I need to change anything. It's exactly what I am looking to implement for my dictionary. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a parameter after pformat:

Before

```
pformat(value))
```

After:

```
pformat(value, function))
```

then change the typo error: formatfunc to function

This is the working code:

```
import collections
import numbers

def formatfloat(x):
    return "%.3g" % float(x)

def pformat(dictionary, function):
    if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        return type(dictionary)((key, pformat(value, function)) for key, value in dictionary.items())
    if isinstance(dictionary, collections.Container):
        return type(dictionary)(pformat(value, function) for value in dictionary)
    if isinstance(dictionary, numbers.Number):
        return function(dictionary)
    return dictionary

x={'a':[1.05600000001,2.34581736481,[8.1111111112,9.999990111111]], 
   'b':[3.05600000001,4.34581736481,[5.1111111112,6.999990111111]]}

pformat(x, formatfloat)
```

Result:

```
{'a': ['1.06', '2.35', ['8.11', '10']], 'b': ['3.06', '4.35', ['5.11', '7']]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here just syntax errors inside.

You call function `pformat` inside without needed arguments. You pass only *value* and not pass *function*

```py
return type(dictionary)((key, pformat(value)) for key, value in dictionary.items())
```

And in last `if` statement you call not implemented function `formatfunc`. Maybe it is typo and you need to call `formatfloat` function.

If fix this, result:

```
{'a': ['1.06', '2.35', ['8.11', '10']], 'b': ['3.06', '4.35', ['5.11', '7']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote it slightly different:

```
x={'a':[1.05600000001,2.34581736481,[8.1111111112,9.999990111111]], 
   'b':[3.05600000001,4.34581736481,[5.1111111112,6.999990111111]]}


def recursive_rounding(keys, values):
    to_return = {}
    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        print key, value
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            rounded_value = recursive_rounding(value.keys(), value.values())
        elif isinstance(value, (tuple, list)):
            rounded_value = [round_by_type(x) for x in value]
        else:
            rounded_value = round_by_type(value)
        print key, value
        to_return[round_by_type(key)] = rounded_value
    return to_return

def round_by_type(to_round):
    if isinstance(to_round, (int, float)):
        return round(to_round, 2)
    elif isinstance(to_round, (list, tuple)):
        return [round_by_type(x) for x in to_round]
    return to_round

recursive_rounding(x.keys(), x.values())
```

I wrote it super quickly and could be cleaned a little and be improved, but just to show somewhat how you could approach it from a different perspective

OUTPUT IS:

```
# Result: {'a': [1.06, 2.35, [8.11, 10.0]], 'b': [3.06, 4.35, [5.11, 7.0]]} #
```