# How to round nested data

Tags: python, nested

Is there a way to recursively round all decimals in any nested data structure that includes lists, dictionaries?

I tried everything here, but the answers are rather outdated:
[Rounding decimals in nested data structures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076254/rounding-decimals-in-nested-data-structures-in-python)

Comment: The stuff over there was written for Python 2 by and large, but it's not *that* hard to convert. `.iter{items|keys|values}` should omit the `iter` part of the name. `print` needs parentheses around the arguments. Collection ABCs come from `collections.abc`, not `collections`. Everything else still applies AFAICT.

Comment: And I've just edited the answers with Py2 specific crud to Py3 (given Py2 has been dead for years now) so those answers there will all work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating @agf's answer from your linked thread to modern 3.x is quite simple, and seems to deliver what you need:

```py
from collections.abc import Container

import numbers
def pformat(thing, formatfunc):
    if isinstance(thing, dict):
        return type(thing)((key, pformat(value, formatfunc)) for key, value in thing.items())
    if isinstance(thing, Container):
        return type(thing)(pformat(value, formatfunc) for value in thing)
    if isinstance(thing, numbers.Number):
        return formatfunc(thing)
    return thing
   
def formatfloat(thing):
   return "%.3g" % float(thing)

x={'a':[1.05600000001,2.34581736481,[8.1111111112,9.999990111111]],
'b':[3.05600000001,4.34581736481,[5.1111111112,6.999990111111]]}

# returns: {'a': ['1.06', '2.35', ['8.11', '10']], 'b': ['3.06', '4.35', ['5.11', '7']]}
```

Comment: You'd need to get `Container` from `collections.abc`, not `collections`, to keep it functional on new Python releases (the docs claim the compatibility import of those names to `collections` ended with 3.10, not sure if they actually pulled the trigger). From 3.3 onwards, `collections.abc` exists with those names.